# Merging nurbs sphere with cylinder

Tags: nurbs-surface

I want to merge the nurbs sphere with a cylinder as shown in the image below. I am a bit new to blender and very unsure how to go about doing it. The way I learnt to merge two objects is with ctrl + j but this does not work in this case.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it:

1. Add your UV/Nurbs sphere.
2. Go into 'Edit Mode' and select the top faces then delete them like so:
   [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/ce2c52ff652200f3d386a1419ca0de27)
3. Go into edge mode and, whilst holding 'ALT' click the one next to it select the ring:
   [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/c0375eeddc46f70e38f751afb7e44630)
4. Press 'E' then 'Z' to extrude that ring a little bit on the 'Z' axis
   [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/3ef97b173cd239c564c48085c1d86677)
5. Press CTRL+R to add about 3 loop cuts (scroll on mouse to increase number of cuts. For a sharper connection add 3 cuts or 4 depending on what you want.
   [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/8e67b311aea99c66a14189e62a4e9e97)
6. Using the 'Ring Select' method I described above, select the open ring and, again, extrude it up a little.
   [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/76cab96bd6ca452a691d720ed48616f0)
7. Now add a SINGLE loop cut, as we did before, but this time, when you've done it, press CTRL+B to bevel it - using your scroll wheel to add 3 or 4 new edges.
   [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/e5e4df7160470a59303f5dde974b88c1)

8.Move them up so that they're just below that top edge.
[EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/0c62a6c404d983d263bab91d4d1b378c)

9. Now select all of those top vertices and move them up to the desired height.
   [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/ead30e8a047fae6677d2ccbbae7415fe)
10. Once again select that top open ring using the 'ALT' and click method.
11. Press 'F' to cap it.
12. Go into face select mode and select that new face.
13. Press I to inset that face by about 0.004, pretty much a tiny amount. You can change the values in the bottom left...
    [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/48a102a65e577d0c11659a66bc3c9231)
14. Now add about 8 edge cuts, or as many as you need so that there are an even number of edges in-between the top and bottom of the cylinder.
    [EXAMPLE](https://gyazo.com/eac4f08acd0aa725b4ce69d04202cbb2)
15. Come out of 'Edit Mode' right click you mesh and choose 'Shade Smooth'
16. Now add a 'Subsurface Modifier' and change the 'Levels Viewport' to 2 or 3 depending on what you'like.
17. You should now have this result:
    [image: Finished Object]

Comment: Thanks! just what I wanted.